# Sum displayed elements

Tags: php

I would like to know how to make a sum of all displayed elements on PHP, I have a database of foods with the numbers of Proteins, Carbs, and Fat that each type of food contains, so I have another table where users input the food they are eating and the portion, so I multiply the amount of proteins, carbs, and fat by the portion, giving me a different value than what it is in the database.
So for instance in the database a bar of chocolate has 0 protein, 1 carbs, and 0.5 fat, so if the user inputs 0.5 portion, then the printed out value is 0 protein 0.5 carbs and 0.25 fat.

I have tried doing SUM() but that sums the values that are in the database.
I tried adding the variable with the results with a loop and it doesn't add the values correctly.

```
<?php  for($i=0;$i<count($resultado);$i++){
    $porcion = $resultado[$i]['porcion1']; //this holds the portion value which could be 1, 0.75, 0.50 or 0.25
    $proteina = $resultado[$i]['proteina'];//this hold protein value
    $carbs = $resultado[$i]['carbs'];//this hold carbs value
    $grasa = $resultado[$i]['grasa'];//this hold fat value

    $tp = (float)$porcion * (float)$proteina;
    $tc = (float)$porcion * (float)$carbs;
    $tg = (float)$porcion * (float)$grasa;
 ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php 
                  $orgDate = $resultado[$i]['dia'];
                  $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($orgDate));
                  echo $newDate ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $resultado[$i]['alimento']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $tp; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $tc; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $tg; ?></td>

                </tr>
         <?php } ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

I expect to be able to sum the result after multiplying portion * protein, carb and fat, and display it in a total at the footer of the page.

[image: snap]

Comment: Where's the code to sum up anything? Can you provide your attempts, and explain which results are given?

Comment: on the code there is a for loop that iterates through the data from 2 tables, the value from one table is multiplied by the value of the user input, for example:
$tp = (float)$porcion * (float)$proteina;
$porcion is the users input and $proteina is pulled from a database, the result of the multiplication is in the variable $tp. So I was stuck trying to add all the results in $tp. so I made an empty variable to add up all the results from $tp and print all the totals ($total_tp)

Comment: There is no code given to sum something up. Please edit your question such that it contains your attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sum = 0 ;
$tptotal = 0;
for($i=0;$i<count($resultado);$i++){
    $tp = (float)$porcion * (float)$proteina;

    $tptotal = $tptotal + $tp;
    $tc = (float)$porcion * (float)$carbs;
    $tg = (float)$porcion * (float)$grasa;

    $sum = $tp+$tc+$tg;
}
```

`$tptotal` or `$sum` should give the answer. Try it.

Comment: I tried it but it only shows the value of the last printed element, it doesn't add them up.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do the sum by creating a variable to add each result and then print the variable:

```
<?php  
    $total_tp = 0;
    $total_tc = 0;
    $total_tg = 0;

    for($i=0;$i<count($resultado);$i++){
        $porcion = $resultado[$i]['porcion1']; //this holds the portion value which could be 1, 0.75, 0.50 or 0.25
        $proteina = $resultado[$i]['proteina'];//this hold protein value
        $carbs = $resultado[$i]['carbs'];//this hold carbs value
        $grasa = $resultado[$i]['grasa'];//this hold fat value

        $tp = (float)$porcion * (float)$proteina;
        $tc = (float)$porcion * (float)$carbs;
        $tg = (float)$porcion * (float)$grasa;

        $total_tp += $tp;
        $total_tc += $tc;
        $total_tg += $tg;
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php 
                $orgDate = $resultado[$i]['dia'];
                $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($orgDate));
                echo $newDate ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $resultado[$i]['alimento']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $tp; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $tc; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $tg; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>    
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <th class="col-md-8">Total</th>
            <td id="totals1"><?php echo $total_tp ?></td>
            <td id="totals2"><?php echo $total_tc ?></td>
            <td id="totals3"><?php echo $total_tg ?></td>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Comment: is it that i posted before $tptotal?

Comment: You know what.. you're right, the thing is I misunderstood what you said, but yeah basically it is. Thank you.